Square Textures
So I'm experiencing this issue where my Porsche still has square reflections even though it is shaded smooth and is subdivided. Any suggestions or help is welcome


hello please share your file (the hood only): https://blend-exchange.com/

The pixellation does not line up with mesh-edges, so consider the mapping / other problems with the reflected image.. Does the pixellation still occur with a plain-colored background?

Without seeing the scene and shaders only guesses are possible. This question is not possible to answer with any certainty with the info provided. Looks a bit like double geometry though.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
